# How to run this for loop in an if statement VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I am looking to put number 1 to 5[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAXp8.png)0 in a column when a particular condition is met for example when i use the below code

```
Sub Macro6()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
Cells(i, 2). Value = i
Next i
End Sub
```

when i run the code the series 1 to 5 is printed in column 2
what i want is If say cells(i,1) = "Condition" then the series 1 to 10 is printed in Cells(i, 2)
What i intended to get is when "condition" is met in one single cell in a column the number 1 to 5 is printed in the next column starting from the corresponding cells and below till 5

I tried to run the code below

```
Dim i As Integer
If cells(i, 1) = "condition"
For i = 1 To 25
Cells(i, 2). Value = i
Next i
End if
```

Its not running and showing some error which i cant figure out

Comment: In your 2nd example, `i=0` and `Cells(0, 1)` is invalid. You can't make up your mind about 5, 10, or 25. Please do so. A more relevant screenshot of your data may also be useful. Please edit your question by adding the clarification and any additional information.

Comment: Also, it looks like your `If` is missing a `Then`

Comment: Just curious, if cell c1 and c2 value is "condition" then what happen in column D?

Answer (score 1):

from your example pic

```
Sub generate()
   Dim i As Integer
   If Cells(1, "C").Value = "Condition" Then
       For i = 1 To 25
          Cells(i, "D").Value = i
       Next i
   End if
End Sub
```

output

[image]

Comment: Please bear with me, i don't know much about vba, i am just trying some simple coding which apparently is not simple for me.

Comment: Thanks all for sharing your feedback i used the suggested code as above by k1dr0ck  i used For i = 1 to 5 the output was 5 in the first cell and that was it.  I am looking for a series of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in the rows below

Comment: @kripalrathod with the code above if C1 is equal to string value "Condition" it will enter values 1 to 25 starting at D1 to D25, see output pic

Comment: If Cells(i, "C") = "Cond" Then
           For i = 1 To 25
           Cells(i + k, "D") = i
           k = k + 1
           Next c
           k = 0
        End If    This solved my problem, what was happening in the prior code was the series were overwritten in the same cell, the above code solved the problem. Thanks k1dr0ck for all your inputs.